# AJAX gets 403 until I refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, cakephp

I have a site that uses `ajax` to store data so that the page does not need to be refreshed. I leave the page open all the time. When the session expires, I can manually refresh the page and the session will be restored. However, if the session expires and I try to send an `ajax` request to the server, the response will be a `403 forbidden` error.

Why can I manually refresh the page and have the session restored, but if I do an `ajax` request the session is not restored?

I have tried having an `ajax` request call the very same page that I am on to see if that would cause the session to refresh, to no avail.

From what I have read, an `ajax` request is the same as a manual request. So doing `ajax` calls should be refreshing the session just the same as reloading the page. But apparently this is not the case.

It is interesting to note that if I let my session expire (or delete the cookie, or remove the session file from the server) and then try an `ajax` call in a for loop it will continually return a `403`. Then if I open another window and load the same page, the session will refresh and the `ajax` responses in the original window will immediately change from `403` to `200`.

What am I missing?

(For reference, I am using CakePHP framework, Nginx web server, on Ubuntu linux.)

Comment: Can you show us your controller code which handles the Ajax call? Might be that you're authenticating

Comment: I am trying to think of which code it would be helpful to show. There is a lot that is handled behind the scenes by the framework. I have tried pointing the Ajax call to different actions in different controllers to see if there would be any change in results.

Comment: Ok, for kicks I decided to point the Ajax call at the login action in the users controller. Lo and behold, it actually refreshed the session. I am not exactly sure why that worked and calling the other actions did not. So for the moment, my problem is solved, though I would like to understand why it worked.

Comment: The thought occurred to me that during manual browsing, if the session was expired the is probably some automatic redirecting going on. An Ajax call may not be following the same redirects.